# Без тире перед "не"

Tags: пунктуация

*Красноперекопск не Индия.* Без тире ведь?

Answer (score 4):

> *Красноперекопск не Индия.* Без тире ведь?

.

**Возможны оба варианта**  — и с тире, и без тире. Решение принимает автор текста.

.

Из ответа [**Грамоты.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=276608):

> Обычно тире не ставится, когда между подлежащим и сказуемым,
>   выраженными существительными, стоит отрицание *не*. **Но интонационное
>   тире возможно**.

.

Из **Розенталя** (В.А. Добромыслов и Д.Э. Розенталь *"Трудные вопросы грамматики и правописания"*, М., 1958 ):

> Приводимая в некоторых пособиях оговорка о ненужности тире,  если при
>   сказуемом имеется отрицание, **не носит категорического характера**…

.

Ещё из [**Розенталя**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/42.htm):

> …**Тире ставится, если имеет целью логически и интонационно
>   подчеркнуть сказуемое**, например: *Но объяснение – не оправдание*
>   (Горький); *«Кровь людская – не водица»* (Стельмах).

Answer (score 1):

**Красноперекопск не Индия.**

**Постановка тире зависит от контекста, возможны оба варианта.**

Пояснение

1)  **В общем случае** тире между подлежащим и составным именным сказуемым **однозначно**  ставится только **при наличии слов-связок** (это, это значит и т.д.), во всех остальных случаях  возможны **оба варианта**. В то же время это не означает, что можно ставить или не ставить тире безо всякой мотивации.

**Интонационно при постановке тире:** 1)  делается пауза в устной речи; 2) ударение падает на подлежащее, логически выделяя его. Такое выделение должно соответствовать авторской задаче.

2) **При наличии частицы НЕ** интонационно возможны оба варианта, поэтому при постановке тире выделяется подлежащее,  а при отсутствии ― сказуемое.

**Примеры**

Конечно, **Иркутск не Москва**, полицейский аппарат действует здесь медленнее, но и город меньше, так что новый человек больше на виду. [М. А. Осоргин. Свидетель истории (1932)] .

Почему **Россия — не Москва**. [Юлия Вишневецкая. Почему Россия — не Москва // «Русский репортер», № 43 (122), 12-19 ноября 2009, 2009]ю А город Калининград ― **не Москва-столица**. [Татьяна Устинова. Персональный ангел (2002)]

Answer (score 0):

Тире не требуется. Хотя встречается и [такое](https://regnum.ru/news/polit/2153077.html).

Comment: да уж....видела....но грамматика говорит, что тире не ставится, если есть "не"

Comment: Не ставится. Это распространенная ошибка. Возьмите хоть известное "Курица не птица..." - пяток различных написаний да найдете.